# how do i get the id of the a href which is dynamic in nature in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

i have the table of rows which are dynamic in nature from server side script (PHP)
so each and every first  td in the row of every table will have the context menu 
(jquery plugin) applied .

How do i get the attribute id(which is dynamic in nature)   of 
 when ever the 
first item of context menu is clicked

```
 $("#mytable td:first-child").contextMenu("myMenu1",{
      bindings: {
            'hdr': function(t) {
                  alert($(this).closest("td").find("a").attr("id"));

             }
      },
      menuStyle: {
            border: '1px solid #000'
       }
      });
```

But my problem from the above code   it is returning same id called "test0" for each and every row .
But my also goal is to get the value of data-value1 (dynamic) for a href tag  on each row 
when ever the first menu item is clicked in the contextmenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://www.trendskitchens.co.nz/jquery/contextmenu/):

> **bindings**
>   An object containing "id":function pairs. The supplied function is the action to be performed when the associated item is clicked. **The element that triggered the current menu is passed to this handler as the first parameter.**

So you have a parameter `t` that should refer to the element you clicked in order to get the context menu.

Try this:

```
alert( $( t ).closest("td").find("a").attr("id") );
```

Comment: @patrickdw: the above statement has helped me to solve it How do i get the data-value of that ,< a href >

Comment: @Someone - Are you saying you want the `href` attribute value? Just do `.attr("href")` instead of `.attr("id")`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @patrick: i want to get the data-value  attribute of the <a href>

Comment: @Someone - What is a "data-value attribute"?

Comment: @Patrick: data-value attribute is HTML5 attribute Please refer this link 
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/customattributes.shtml 
<a href="abc.php" id ="Test0" data-city="$row['SOmeColumn Value']" data-State="$row['SOmeColumn Value']"  data-country="$row['SOmeColumn Value']">
i have said in this manner but it did not work 
alert( $( t ).closest("td").find("a").attr("data-city") );

Comment: @Someone - Not sure. If you do `alert( $( t ).closest("td").find("a").length );`, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If it's the first element of a `<tr>`, for example, you could do something like this:

`var yourID = $("tr.yourClass td:first").attr("id")`